# Rails show custom label for attribute in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure this has already been asked and it's pretty easy but I don't really know what to search to find a solution.

If I have values in a column table like `1,-1,2` where `-1 = sale`, `1 = purchase` etc, how do I show purchase instead of 1 or sale instead of -1?

Database table `stockmovements` column name `reason`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I face such situation I create a readable_method in model.

In your model class add method like this:

```
def readable_reason
    case reason
    when -1
        "sale"
    when 1
        "purchase"
    end
end
```

Then In your view,

```
<td>stockmovement.readable_reason</td>
```

It keeps my view file more readable. Also I don't have to copy `case-when` in every view where I want to show `reason`.

Comment: Yes this is the best approach to avoid repetition and keep things clear. I'm going to use this one. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I tried it just now and it returns an error. first I have to use self.reason to make it work, but then it returns last value for all rows. In your example above it returns purchase for all rows

Comment: @catmal are you sure? This is similar rubyfiddle http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/8d0ae . Case when works perfectly

Comment: Sorry I added conditions to your code and I've put an `end` by mistake. All good it works now thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<% if stockmovement == 1 %>
 purchase
<% elsif stockmovement == -1 %>
 sale
<% end %>
```

Comment: Same as the other answer needs to be stockmovement.reason

Answer (score 1):

Inside your table's document you should put:

```
<td>
  <% case stockmovement %>
  <% when 1 %>
    "purchase"
  <% when 2 %>
    "sale"
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: ok it's actually stockmovement.reason and then it works.. Thanks a lot!